# Using data points lying within certain isochrone to model walking routes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, merge, isochrone

I am trying to model the routes students take to university on foot using QGIS. I have the student data in point form, but this is the student data for the whole city. I also have an isochrone which displays walking distance one hour from the university. I have too many data points for student location and do not need the data points that lie outside the isochrone.

Is there a way on QGIS where I can only use the student data points within the isochrone and plot those routes to the university? A way of merging the two data sets or having a file of the student data location within the boundary of the isochrone?

Comment: Are you asking how to use select by location or select within distance tool ?

Comment: Your isochrone is a polygon layer? A raster? You want what: to get the "route" to the university, that means you want a line layer? Or just the number of minutes a studend needs to reach university? Sorry, the question is quite confusing. Please add more information about the data you have. Can you also post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi, I managed to answer my own question using vector selection --> extract by location. Thank you though!